# VBA-Explorer drop down menu selecting

Tags: excel, explorer, vba

I am a rookie to programming and am pretty sure that I am way over my head, but here is my problem. I work at a manufacturing facility that has a server that I do not have (and cannot have) access to. In order to retrieve and analyze data I have to go onto our Quality Management website which presents multiple drop down menus to select from. The first one is "Manufacturing date", then time, then machine ID, and then run the search. This then opens a new window that contains the data I need to insert into a previously written macro to organize. My buddy from work found this program:

```
Sub GoogleSearch()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

WebSite = "http://mant6websrv1.thermatru.com/QMS/QualityReporting/Reports/LDMasterQueryReport.asp"

With objIE

    .Visible = True

    .navigate WebSite

    Do While .Busy Or .readystate <> 4

        DoEvents

    Loop

    Set Element = .document.getElementsByName("q")

    Element.Item(0).Value = "Hello world"

    .document.forms(0).submit

    '.quit

    End With

End Sub
```

It was originally a google search program that opens google in explorer and then searches the phrase "hello world". By simply replacing the website with our Quality Management address we have been able to get it to open the correct site, but I have no idea how to get it to select the options I want. I tinkered around a bit with the webdeveloper for explorer and even found the ID names for the boxes I need to fill out...but have no idea how to get the program to select them, and then insert the dates I want and run the search. Any ideas??

p.s. when I say I am a rookie I mean that this is my third day writing macros with vba so please be as simplistic and clear as possible with any answers. I am starting to really enjoy this stuff and want to learn  as much as possible. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the web macro recorder in [Open Twebst](http://open-twebst.codecentrix.com/). Record the actions you want to take and put the code in Excel's VB editor. In your case you can use VBScript, which can for the most part also be used with VBA. You might not get perfect result immediately with a recording, but it's a good tool to help you get on the right track, even if you may need to tinker with the code a bit and look through the HTML of the site to get perfect control.

Note however that it has its own framework for web automation, it's not recording using the standard Microsoft web libraries for it.